# Set background color in a smooth way

Tags: javascript, animation, background-color

I've got the following JS code:

```
// utility function to convert r,g,b to html color
function RGB2HTML(red, green, blue) {
    var decColor =0x1000000+ blue + 0x100 * green + 0x10000 *red ;
    return '#'+decColor.toString(16).substr(1);
}

// recursive utility function to animate color
// elNames an array of Ids (these are mainly TDs)
// curCnt is current animation step
// totSteps is total steps
function pulseBGMany(elNames, curCnt, totSteps) {
    for(var i=0; i < elNames.length; ++i) {
        var curEl = document.getElementById(elNames[i]);
        var curColor = RGB2HTML(255, 255*(curCnt/totSteps), 255*(curCnt/totSteps));
        curEl.style.backgroundColor = curColor;
    }
    if(curCnt < totSteps) {
        setTimeout( function(){ pulseBGMany(elNames, curCnt+1, totSteps); }, 40);
    }
}

// eventually in another piece of code, it all gets triggered
...
// schedule ui update here!
// use a closure
(function(names){ setTimeout( function(){ pulseBGMany(names, 0, 25); }, 40)})(diffRes);
...
```

The code above works, but unfortunately the animation is *very*  chopped and I'm not able to see a smooth gradient from **red** to **white**; it seems like all major browsers are *losing* frames (tested on Firefox and Chromium on Ubuntu).
The array of *TDs* varies from 1 to even 80 elements, but the effect is always the same.

What am I doing wrong?

As requested, JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/PsvCP/2/ (You have to set *No wrap in body*)

Thanks,
Ema

Comment: Are you deadset against using jQuery? It has `animate()` and `pulse()` methods that are exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Before using _jQuery_, I would like to understand things. On top of this I might not need the whole _jQuery_ in this simple webpage. Sorry mate, but this question is _not_ about _jQuery_.

Comment: Can you set up a simple jsFiddle? Problems like this are easier to solve if we can see them :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've gotten around it. Apparently the `setTimeout` API is particularly slow in both Chrom(ium) and Firefox. Scheduling all the gradient function calls in *advance* is much more efficient for current browsers and does the trick:

```
// non-recursive utility function to animate color
function pulseBGMany(elNames, curCnt, totSteps) {
  var curColor = RGB2HTML(255, 255*(curCnt/totSteps), 255*(curCnt/totSteps));
  for(var i=0; i < elNames.length; ++i) {
    elNames[i].style.backgroundColor = curColor;
  }
}

...
  // schedule ui update here!
  // use a closure
  var numFade = 15;
  for(var i=0; i < numFade; ++i) {
    (function(names, iter, tot){ setTimeout( function(){ pulseBGMany(names, iter+1, numFade); }, 50*iter)})(diffRes, i, numFade);
  }
...
```

and as expected this works a *lot* faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try doubling the amount of steps, 25fps is somewhat choppy.
Doubling the steps should put you at 50fps which should be fine.

Also make the elmntlist a array of dom elements and not a array of element id's,
Dom lookups are really slow and probaply causing most of your problems.

Comment: When you say "array of dom elements" do you mean that I should create the array with the output of `document.getElementById(...)`?

Comment: Doubled the steps, halved the timeout, used an array of _DOM elements_ but the choppiness doesn't go away...